# SSO Snowflake and Keycloak. Unkown login requester

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does anyone set up Keycloak for SSO with Snowflake. I've created a client in Keycloak. From the opening page of Snowflake I'm redirected to Keycloak. There I got the error:

'Unkown login requester'

From what I found online it should have something to do with the ClientID, but I can't figure out what it should be. Anyone facing the same issue and know how to solve it?

Comment: You need to check Client ID in keycloak and in the advanced section in SSO(SAML) settings

Comment: I found out that the ClientID should be the same as  SAML2_SNOWFLAKE_ISSUER_URL, https://xxxxx.snowflakecomputing.com/